# JQuery Detecting Hover on Flash Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problem with the following JQuery code:

```
$("object").hover(function(e){
   alert('Flash Here');
});
```

I just want jquery to detect if I hover on top of the flash object.

Here is the flash embed code:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000"
 codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0"
 width="320" height="240" quality="HIGH"><param name="movie"
 value="test.swf"><param name="quality" value="high">
<embed src="rdream.swf"
 quality="high" width="320" height="240" name="Test"
 type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
 pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">
</object>
```

I'm not getting the alert as expected.

Comment: You asked to detect the 'flash object' which my code does, not the container for the flash object. Detecting the element (the div you hope flash will be loaded in) that the flash resides in, doesn't mean that flash was loaded or not. It just means that div (the element in this case) is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to insert the flash into some block element and hover that instead of the object.

```
<div id="myFlash">
  <object>
  Your Flash...
  </object>
</div>

$("#myFlash").hover(function(e){
   alert('Flash Here');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>
div#container{z-index:2;width:320px;height:240px;}
div#flashcontainer{z-index:1;width:320px;height:240px;overflow:hidden;border:solid 1px red;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

//detecting the div container doesnt mean flash was loaded
//$('#flashcontainer').hover(function(){
//alert(this.id);
//});

//detect the id from the flash embed code
$('object').hover(function(){
alert(this.id);
});

});
</script>

<div id="container">

<div id="flashcontainer">

<object classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' width='320' height='240' id='player1' name='player1'>
<param name='movie' value='test.swf'>
<param name='allowfullscreen' value='true'>
<param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>
<param name='wmode' value='transparent'>
<embed id='player1'
name='player1'
src='test.swf'
width='320'
height='240'
allowscriptaccess='always'
allowfullscreen='true'
flashvars="wmode=transparent"
/>
</object>

</div>

</div>
```